# Custom indentation rule for eslint in arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, indentation, eslint

I could not find any standard rules for such indentation in arrays and objects. I need aliment by identificators ( ignoring brackets ). For our code style this approach is more convinient.

```
    // default indent is 4 spaces
    webix.ui({
        view: "popup",
        id: "group_name_edit",
        position: "center",
        body: {
            padding: 20,
            rows: [
                input,
              { cols: [    //       <-------- sample line
                  {},
                  { view: "button",
                    label: "Ok",
                    width: 150,
                  },
                ] 
              }
            ]
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the `indent` and [`object-curly-newline`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline) rules:

```
  rules: {
    "indent": ["error", 4, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
    "object-curly-newline": ["error", { "minProperties": 1 }]
  },
```

I copied your sample and applied auto-fix and this is the result:

```
webix.ui({
    view: "popup",
    id: "group_name_edit",
    position: "center",
    body: {
        padding: 20,
        rows: [
            input,
            {
                cols: [    
                    {},
                    {
                        view: "button",
                        label: "Ok",
                        width: 150,
                    },
                ] 
            }
        ]
    },
});
```

If you also want to enforce line breaks in arrays (which is not neccessary based on the given sample, as there already are line breaks), you could also add `array-bracket-newline: ["error", "always"]` to the rules.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this approach, but at first glance it's not the same I try to find, actually I don't need a new line for bracket, they should be placed on the same line with 1st element of object (I found and use this option in eslint). In this case you get shot code by x-y dimensions and clear bracket position, at least it is one of approaches of our command.